# VBA functions in one workbook, but not another, no errors found

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, find-replace, fieldcodes

I have an .xlsm workbook where this VBA (see below) interacts with a Word Document to replace field codes.  Seems straight forward, and it worked great...

Then I copied and pasted the code into a new .xlsm, checked the cells, sheet names, and contents, all is the same!  The VBA will run, and I get no errors.  However, with the new .xlsm, the field codes will no longer be replaced in the document!  I have not found anything online which is helpful... Thoughts?

as a side note, I'm not sure if this is related or not, but my "num lock" turns on/off at times during testing this script/function.

```
Sub Exl_to_Wrd_FieldReplace()
'
' Exl_to_Wrd_FieldReplaceMacro
'
' Setup info for document and captures default DIR for Document
    Dim wordapp As Object
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim wordDoc As String
    folderPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path
    wordDoc = folderPath & "\TestDoc.docx"
'
' Assign Excel cell values for Field Code Text Replacement
    Dim CaseNum As String: CaseNum = Range("C36").Value
    Dim P1LastName As String: P1LastName = Range("C41").Value
    Dim P2FInl As String: P2FInl = Range("C53").Value
    Dim P2LastName As String: P2LastName = Range("C54").Value
    Dim P2ID As String: P2ID = Range("C55").Value
'
' Open Word application and document
    Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
    wordapp.Documents.Open (wordDoc) 'Uses path from above & Doc name
    wordapp.Visible = True
    wordapp.Activate
'
' Converts Field Vaule text to Field Codes (i.e. ALT + F9)
    SendKeys "%{F9}"
'
' Starts the Find Command to replace field code with hard coded text
    With wordapp.ActiveDocument.Content.Find
'
' Finds 1st field code
        .Text = "^d DOCPROPERTY  IBA|CaseNumber  \* MERGEFORMAT"
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = CaseNum
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
' Finds 2nd field code
        .Text = "^d DOCPROPERTY  IBA|P1LastName  \* MERGEFORMAT"
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = P1LastName
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
' Finds 3rd field code
        .Text = "^d DOCPROPERTY  IBA|P2FirstInitial  \* MERGEFORMAT"
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = P2FInl 
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
' Finds 4th field code
        .Text = "^d DOCPROPERTY  IBA|P2LastName  \* MERGEFORMAT"
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = P2LastName 
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
' Finds 5th field code
        .Text = "^d DOCPROPERTY  IBA|P2Number  \* MERGEFORMAT"
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Text = P2ID
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
'        
    End With
'
' Converts Field Codes back to Field Vaule text (i.e. ALT + F9)
    SendKeys "%{F9}"
'
' It is ok to leave doc open, user needs to do final check/edit before save
'
End Sub
```

I checked both excel sheets, links, VBA and Xml, all is the same.

Comment: Why are you replacing the field codes rather than just updating the document property values so that the fields return the values you want?

Comment: We have a system going offline for a long period of time, based on the volume of documents needed to process, we feel a replacement of field codes is more efficient during this time.  The documents in the end will be PDF, so the hard coding is acceptable.

Comment: I honestly don't see how this is more efficient, especially if it doesn't work. ;)

Comment: @Rory Everything is less efficient when VBA doesn't work.  The reality is, It worked in the first workbook I created, now it doesn't in a new workbook with the same code, same names, and same directory.  I'm asking the forum to help to understand the volatility of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Using SendKeys usually is highly unreliable.
To toggle the display of fields in word, you can use `ShowFieldCodes`, which is a Property of a `View`-object, and that is a property of a `Window`.

```
With wordApp.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View
    .ShowFieldCodes = True                 ' Shows the Code
    .ShowFieldCodes = False                ' Shows the Content 
    .ShowFieldCodes = Not .ShowFieldCodes  ' Toggles the setting (this is what Alt+F9 does) 
End With
```

Comment: Thank you @FunThomas !  I just tried this, but I have the same issue.  With your proposal, it works the same way as Alt+F9 did.  I had issues earlier with .showFieldCodes hence the SendKeys.  In any case, the document toggles between show and hide codes, but still does not replace the text.  Is there a better way to select the entire FieldCode which contains a certain text, instead of the entire explicit name?  it seems the .Find and .Replace is not consistent in this case between workbooks.